# How to scale in and out objects individual with pinch zoom

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, pinchzoom

I find this script for pinch zoom but this is for camera zoom in and out please tell me how it can works for objects and more important thing is for individual objects it means if i want to scale cube then only cube is scaled nothing else at the same time. and if sphere then only sphere thanks.
here's code:

```
using UnityEngine;
{
public float perspectiveZoomSpeed = 0.5f;        // The rate of change of the field of view in perspective mode.
public float orthoZoomSpeed = 0.5f;        // The rate of change of the orthographic size in orthographic mode.
 void Update()
{
    // If there are two touches on the device...
    if (Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        // Store both touches.
        Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

        // Find the position in the previous frame of each touch.
        Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
        Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

        // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the touches in each frame.
        float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
        float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

        // Find the difference in the distances between each frame.
        float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

        // If the camera is orthographic...
        if (camera.isOrthoGraphic)
        {
            // ... change the orthographic size based on the change in distance between the touches.
            camera.orthographicSize += deltaMagnitudeDiff * orthoZoomSpeed;

            // Make sure the orthographic size never drops below zero.
            camera.orthographicSize = Mathf.Max(camera.orthographicSize, 0.1f);
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise change the field of view based on the change in distance between the touches.
            camera.fieldOfView += deltaMagnitudeDiff * perspectiveZoomSpeed;

            // Clamp the field of view to make sure it's between 0 and 180.
            camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(camera.fieldOfView, 0.1f, 179.9f);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Logic of such process would be: 1. On first touch mark the object to scale (look for raycasts and hit) in some variable like `markedGameObject`. 2. Use your code to determine  `deltaMagnitudeDiff`. 3. Delete whole `if -else` statement from your code. 4. Replace it with something like `markedGameObject.localScale = deltaMagnitudeDiff`. 5. Adjust speed of scaling to your needs. Sorry dont have means to test it, but ask a question when you try it :)

Comment: You are right But i am noob in scripting if you can edit the code for me i am really thankful to you. and thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I cannot test it properly so there maybe some bugs but here's general idea for a code:

IMPORTANT: object has to have collider attached - it will not work without it

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class ObjectScalling : MonoBehaviour {

private GameObject selectedObject;    
//public GameObject gameobject;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if ( Input.touchCount == 0 )
    {
        Touch touch = Input.touches[0];
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if ( Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100f ) )
        {
            selectedObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
        }
    }
    if (Input.touchCount == 2)
    {
        // Store both touches.
        Touch touchZero = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Touch touchOne = Input.GetTouch(1);

        // Find the position in the previous frame of each touch.
        Vector2 touchZeroPrevPos = touchZero.position - touchZero.deltaPosition;
        Vector2 touchOnePrevPos = touchOne.position - touchOne.deltaPosition;

        // Find the magnitude of the vector (the distance) between the touches in each frame.
        float prevTouchDeltaMag = (touchZeroPrevPos - touchOnePrevPos).magnitude;
        float touchDeltaMag = (touchZero.position - touchOne.position).magnitude;

        // Find the difference in the distances between each frame.
        float deltaMagnitudeDiff = prevTouchDeltaMag - touchDeltaMag;

        selectedObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(deltaMagnitudeDiff , deltaMagnitudeDiff , deltaMagnitudeDiff);

    }
}
}
```

It probably contains some bugs, but generally you may start to work on that :) Of course everything goes into your `Update()` except this line: `deltaMagnitudeDiff`

Comment: Thanks i will test it later :)

Comment: THanks for accepting an answer, but maybe you should test it first :)

Comment: yeah i have test it when i drag this script on object no bugs but nothing happens on touch screen

Comment: comment out last line (selectedObject.transform...) to disable it and put a line `Debug.Log(deltaMagnitudeDiff.ToString());` or put a text on your screen and change it text to `deltaMagnitudeDiff.ToString()` so you can see if this code works. Also you may check what object is selected in the similar way. For example by using `DebugText.text = selectedObject.name;`. You will be able to see if the code works and where is a problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106945/discussion-between-mirza-zeeshan-and-lukasz-motyczka).